# Reflection with HashMap

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap

I do have an abstact class, lets call it "GameObjects" and a lot of Child Classes to that like "Stone".
At runtime im parsing a Xml File where i read about the GameObjects that need to be created(like a "Stone") and some additional info about them. To create the specific GameObject i use reflection like this:

```
Class<?> cl = Class.forName("classpath."+typ);
Constructor con = cl.getConstructor(float.class, float.class, float.class, float.class);
Object gameObj = con.newInstance(xPos, yPos, widht, height);
```

Now i want to put the GameObject into a HashMap< String, GameObject> . But this does not work:

```
currentGameObjects.put(name, gameObj);
```

Obviously cause gameObj is of typ Object. What does work is something like:

```
currentGameObjects.put(name, (GameObject)gameObj);
```

But i acutally need something like

```
currentGameObjects.put(name, (Stone)gameObj);
```

Problem is like i said that i dont know at Runtime if its a Stone or Flower or Rainbow or whatever....

Any idea how i can achive that, or a good workaround ?

Edit:
Maybe im thinking to complicated here.
But basiclly my idea was. To have a Map with GameObjects i can iterate through.
So for example i can do thinks like iterate thought currentGameObjects and if its a Stone (instance of Stone) do smth.
Also A Stone can have additional fields Methods compared to the abstract class GameObject ?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to cast to `Stone`/`Flower`/etc.? Casting to `GameObject` seems sufficient, if your `HashMap` is `HashMap<String, GameObject>`...

Comment: What benefit do you expect from `currentGameObjects.put(name, (Stone)gameObj);` over `currentGameObjects.put(name, (GameObject)gameObj);`? Users of the map would still see stones as `GameObject` instances.

Comment: Why do you need reflection? Why can't you simply parse and use appropiate constructor?

Comment: I fail to see the benefit of casting your object to a Stone as the object you can retrieve by get from the Map would be of type GameObject anyway. Maybe there's a misunderstanding on how object oriented programming and inheritance work...

Comment: I agree with @Nicktar that there is probably a misunderstanding of how objects work here. If you have an instance of `Stone`, then it will remain an instance of `Stone`, regardless of the type of the variable used to refer to it. It doesn't devolve into a nonspecific `GameObject` just because you cast - casting only affects *variables*, not *objects*. If i give you a piece of paper and ask you to write the name of an animal on it, and you write the name of your cat, then the cat doesn't suddenly devolve into a nonspecific animal, does it?

Comment: Okay, looks like i had a misunderstanding here, just like you said. But thx for the idea with the Subclass @TomAnderson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Class::asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) to cast your `Class<?>` to a more refined type, then propagate that type through the constructor to the new instance:

```
Class<? extends GameObject> cl = Class.forName("classpath." + typ).asSubclass(GameObject.class);
Constructor<? extends GameObject> con = cl.getConstructor(float.class, float.class, float.class, float.class);
GameObject gameObj = con.newInstance(xPos, yPos, widht, height);
```